# Microsoft Graph: How to get all SharePoint sites for a specific user

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph

I would like to retrieve a list of all SharePoint sites a specific user has access to.

---

I am able to return followed sites for a specific user using the following endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/followedSites
```

I am able to return all sites for the organization using the following endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*
```

---

Using [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) I have tried the following endpoints:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/sites
```

Returns `Resource 'sites' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/sites?search=*
```

Returns `Unrecognized query argument specified: 'search'.`

---

Can I return all sites a specific user has access to?
Alternatively, can I return all users with access to a specific SharePoint site?

Answer (score 0):

Responses from SharePoint are security-trimmed.

If user X requests https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=* then the response you will get will only have those sites that user X has access to. Nothing beyond that.

To submit the call this way, your requests need to use the right OAuth flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user